# Making Floating Boxes in CSS fill the wrapper

Tags: css, html, css-float, jquery-masonry

This is driving me crazy.

I am building a page which will only have a predefined header and footer, the content between them will be a set of boxes (dynamic) that have to be properly positioned in order to fill the wrapper.

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/rdMKQ/1/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="wrapper" >
    <div class="box" style="width:60px;height:60px;background-color:blue"> 1 </div>
    <div class="box" style="width:40px;height:30px;background-color:red"> 2 </div>
    <div class="box" style="width:80px;height:60px;background-color:yellow"> 3 </div>
    <div class="box" style="width:40px;height:30px;background-color:green"> 4 </div>
</div>
```

**Non-Inline CSS:**

```
#wrapper{width:180px;}
.box{float:left}
```

All the boxes `float:left` and the sizes I used are just 'random' as a matter of example

What can I do to position the green box (4) just below red one (2) to fill the gap?

Requirements of the solution:

- I can not define specific styles for a single box, styles should be common to all boxes
- Boxes can not overlap

PD: I've already tried the jQuery Masonry Plugin to let him make the work filling the gap in JS, but no luck, there's no option that does what I need.

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done, but not with your existing HTML flow.

[Here is an example:](http://jsfiddle.net/rdMKQ/3/)

```
<div id="wrapper" >    
    <div class="box" style="width:60px;height:60px;background-color:blue"> 1 </div>
    <div class="box" style="width:40px;height:30px;background-color:red"> 2 </div>
    <div class="box" style="width:40px;height:30px;background-color:green"> 4 </div>
</div>
<div class="box" style="width:80px;height:60px;background-color:yellow;"> 3 </div>
```

And

```
#wrapper{width:100px;height:60px;float:left;}
.box{float:left}
```

Comment: I can not do that either, as i have no way to know which layout will that end up with. So it should be only one container for all boxes

Comment: Elements float in the order of appearance in the HTML. You want them not to. Unless you're going to use JS to calculate and position these items, you're stuck.

Comment: Well 'i can' define the order, so if there is other order that will make it work, that would be a solution!

Comment: About using JS to positioning the elements, thats the reason why i tried the jQuery Masonry plugin, i thought that was going to be the only way, but i have not been able to make it work to solve this specific problem.
Thanks for your input

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like  [this](http://jsfiddle.net/5K4Hk/1/)? The only problem with that is the green box is overlapping the others.

```
<div id="wrapper" >
    <div class="box" style="width:60px;height:60px;background-color:blue"> 1 </div>
    <div class="box" style="width:40px;height:30px;background-color:red"> 2 </div>
    <div class="box" style="width:80px;height:60px;background-color:yellow"> 3 </div>
    <div class="box green" style="height:30px;background-color:green"> 4 </div>    
</div>
```

And

```
#wrapper{width:180px;}
.box{float:left; z-index:5;}
.green{position:relative; clear:both; width:100%; margin-top:-30px; z-index:3;}
```

Comment: Yep, something like that, but as you say, the problem is that boxes shouldnt overlap, and also i can not define an specific CSS style for one box, Styles should be common to all boxes
Thanks

Comment: I can change the `green` class to `.box:last-of-type` which will only select the last `box` class element. One way or another there would be overlapping, the problem would be solved if the green box was overlapped by the others.

Comment: That won't work either, because i as i don't know the layout, there can be many more boxes below with the same (or diferent) sizes